# WCF Callback deadlock

Tags: wcf, callback, deadlock

I ran into a problem with a WCF service that calls a callback method on the client. First the service:

```
[ServiceContract(
SessionMode = SessionMode.Required,
CallbackContract = typeof(IMarketObserver))]
public interface IServer
{
  ...
  [OperationContract]
  [FaultContractAttribute(typeof(WCFFaultDetail))]
  bool NotifyOnMarket(EnumMarkets marketID);
  ...
}
```

Service implementation:

```
[ServiceBehavior(
InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,
ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,
UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
public sealed class Platform : IServer
{
 ...
 public bool NotifyOnMarket(EnumMarkets marketID)
 {
    try
    {
        IMarketObserver callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMarketObserver>();
        if (subscribers.Contains(callback) == false)
        {
            subscribers.Add(callback);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
    //This call may cause a call to the callback method SendMarketData()!!
    callSomeMethod();
    return exchangeProxy.IsMarketIDValid();
}
```

The callback contract:

```
public interface IMarketObserver
{
  [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
  void SendMarketData(MarketData marketData);
}
```

The client implementation of this callback is:

```
[CallbackBehavior(
    ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,
    UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
public class MarketBase : 
    IServerCallback
{
  protected IService serviceProxy;
  public void SendMarketData(MarketData marketData)
  {
      //Do something
  }
  private void NotifyOnMarkets()
  {
      foreach (EnumMarkets item in observedMarkets)
      {
          try
          {
              bool res = serviceProxy.NotifyOnMarket(item);
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
             ...
          }
      }
  }
```

The problem occurs when calling NotifyOnMarkets() with the foreach loop.

If there is only one item in the observedMarkets list, so there is exactly one call to the service's NotifyOnMarket() method and everything is working fine.

But if observedMarkets contains more than one item then NotifyOnMarket() will get called many times with a high frequency to the server.

The implementation of NotifyOnMarket() on the server calls a method which in turn will call the callback method SendMarketData(I commented this fact).

In the traces I can see that serviceProxy.NotifyOnMarket(item); does not return on a second item, a timeout occurs.

On the server side, mutliple calls to NotifyOnMarket() are handled correctly and the method is exited. But as said above, the boolean result will not show up on the client(timeout).

Also, one can see that on the server side the callback is invoked(it is one-way so no response will be returned), but on the client side nothing happens since the callback implementation is not called.

My conclusion is that some kind of a deadlock occured and this maybe due to the client instance which locks itself and so the server can't call the callback method.

Is it better to separate the instance context class from the class which is also performing service calls? If so, why?

Thanks for advice,

Juergen

Answer (score 4):

For your question: Why it needs to be on a different thread?
Read the end of [WCF Duplex Messaging](http://www.dotnetconsult.co.uk/weblog2/PermaLink,guid,b891610a-6b78-4b54-b9a6-4ec81c82b7c0.aspx):

> WCF adds more complexity into the mix by enforcing a rule that says
>   “unless you tell me otherwise I will only allow one thread at a time
>   into an object that I control”. You see this with singleton services
>   that will only allow one call at a time by default. The same is also
>   true of the callback implementation object – so WCF will only allow
>   one active thread in the client at a time. So while WCF is performing
>   an outbound call it will not allow an inbound call into the object.
>   This causes the initial problem with the deadlock that the service’s
>   callback cannot be dispatched while the client’s outbound call is in
>   progress. To solve this we use the “unless you tell me otherwise” part
>   of the above rule. You do this by annotating the callback
>   implementation class with a [CallbackBehavior] attribute like this:

```
[CallbackBehavior(ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant)]
```

Comment: Thx for the link. As you can see with my callback implementation I set the ConcurrencyMode to multiple(I also tried Reentrant). This should allow multiple calls on the client with multiple threads. ConcurrencyMode should be the only statement to tell WCF that I will do synchronisation for myself. But this does not do the job as you can see in the blog post link of my answer. It is no logical solution to use the ThreadPool when ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple should be enough.

Comment: I had a similar problem, it only worked when I added [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant)] on the service implementation class, it didn't work when i put it on the callback class.

Comment: so what was the solution? I know this was years ago, but it's still valuable information to other people. I would have thought your code would work, and that changing it to "re-entrant" wouldn't fix the problem. I'm tempted to duplicate your test and see if it was a bug back in '11 that is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it right by setting it to Multiple or Re-entrant (both work, but re-entrant will force 1 thread at a time, and multiple will allow multiple threads to enter your service at once). I'd personally set it as "re-entrant", unless you need multiple threads entering your service at once.

I just wrote a test  case on my machine here, following your example, and it worked just fine. I think your IIS implementation (back in '11) had a bug in it. Impossible to test, now.